# Scala Slick 2.0 with PostgreSQL. Compare Timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql, scala, slick

I'm using Slick 2.0.0-RC1 with PostgreSQL. How I can compare Timestamp column when I create select query. Suppose I'm trying to make simple query and fetch events with start date after now.

I have column in my table:

```scala
  val start: Column[Option[Timestamp]] = column("start")
```

Query fragment:

```scala
val now = new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime)

val q = for {
  event <- events
  date <- eventDates if event.id === date.id; if date.start > now
} yield (event, date)
```

It compiles to something like:

```sql
AND (x16."start" >= {ts '2014-01-01 00:00:00.0'}))
```

And that's seems to be illegal syntax for postgres. How can I make it right?

Comment: We can't produce this, which version of Postgres were you using?

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.2.4 /w 9.3-1100-jdbc41 driver

Comment: We cannot reproduce the syntax error with postgres 9.1 or 9.3.2. Please try one of these and see if it is still a problem for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a bug. I submitted a ticket: https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/600 We'll look at it.

*Update:* We could not reproduce the problem and closed the ticket.

Comment: Thanks! If it's a bug, maybe I'll try to dig into for a fix.

Answer (score 2):

The SQL the OP quotes:

> `AND (x16."start" >= {ts '2014-01-01 00:00:00.0'}))`

is not the actual SQL run by Postgres. It is the JDBC SQL which utilises the ODBC format of:

> {ts

If you try to run this SQL directly via psql it will complain of

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "{"

I am not sure what the final Postgres SQL will be but I assume JDBC translates it to something like

```
AND (x16.start > timestamp '2014-01-01 00:00:00.0')
```

So in fact the SQL reported by Slick is correct.

I just went down this rabbit hole, with the added distraction (but useful) of using https://github.com/tototoshi/slick-joda-mapper instead of direct timestamps. In the end the root cause of my problem was another column and not the timestamp column being wrongly configured.